# Multiple MapActivitys in the stack

Tags: android, google-maps

I understand this topic has been covered a few times, and often the proposed solution to having 'multiple' MapActivity classes is to run one in a different processes. I don't want to do this, I've got 3.

I've instead refactored one MapActivity Subclass to operate in 3 different modes.

```
package com.rossgreenhalf.maptest.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    /* Inflate xml view, Set Zoom etc */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        int mode = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("MAP_MODE");

        switch(mode){
        case 1:
            /* Some markers to show */
            break;
        case 2:
            /* Just one Marker */
            break;
        case 3: 
            /* Only showing my location */
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
    }
}
```

I'm allowing multiple instances of the MapActivity to reside within the task stack, as it's launch mode is still set as 'Standard'. This approach seems to work ok, and I'm not getting the Connection Pool Shutdown message that some seem to get, I'm a little confused as to whether multiple MapActivity instances actually exist or whether android is reusing one automatically?

I am however getting this error, which I don't know how serious it is:

```
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620): Activity com.rossgreenhalf.maptest.activity.MyMapActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.google.android.maps.NetworkConnectivityListener$ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver@44981cf0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.rossgreenhalf.maptest.activity.MyMapActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.google.android.maps.NetworkConnectivityListener$ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver@44981cf0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher.(ActivityThread.java:968)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:753)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:799)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:786)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:780)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at com.google.android.maps.NetworkConnectivityListener.startListening(MapActivity.java:163)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onResume(MapActivity.java:431)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at com.rossgreenhalf.maptest.activity.MyMapActivity.onResume(MyMapActivity.java:166)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1237)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3864)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3315)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3340)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2158)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-25 10:14:54.433: ERROR/ActivityThread(5620):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Am I taking the correct approach to this? Should I be concerned with that error?

Comment: This error is just told you, what some Receiver is registered and not had been unregistered after activity is shut down. This can lead to memory leak in your application.

Comment: I understand the error, I just don't know it's real impact.

Comment: The impact is potential memory leak in your application.

Comment: @Olegas How to prevent this error?

Comment: @IgorG the solution is straightforward... You need to unregister your receivers in onPause/onStop/onDestroy events, depending on your needs.

Comment: @Olegas  MapActivity comes with the Android SDK.  It isn't something that the user would normally go and modify (unless you know what you are doing).

Comment: @IgorG. we don't have a full source here... Maybe some method like onPause or something is overriden there and super is not called?

Answer (score 6):

I got the same problem and after searching I found this post about the same issue

https://novoda.lighthouseapp.com/projects/63622/tickets/157-leak-receiver-searchresult

it suggests that the problem rises when using multiple `map activities` within your application.

so in **manifest.xml** file of my app I made each **map activity** run in a separate process:

```
android:process=":p1"
android:process=":p2"
```

you can read more about this in Android docs. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#proc